# Get values of Entity Type in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

How do I get the value of dropdown field in controller.

I have drop down fields where values of data is from one of my table in database. Please see the code below.

```
class SubAgentType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('company_id', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Company',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'SwipeBundle:Company',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a Company',
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array("message" => 'Company name is required.')),
            ),            
        )); ../
```

In my html.twig it works fine, it renders the html correctly whereas there's a value numeric and the name of company.

UPDATE:

```
<select id="sub_agent_company_id" name="sub_agent[company_id]" required="required">
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose a Company</option>
<option value="20">20 Incorporated</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
</select>
```

The problem is the entity type is returning the class company object instead of the value of a dropdown only.

How do I get only the values of dropdown instead an object?

here's the screenshot of error in my dropdown companyid [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I want to get the values of my entity type like for example 20, 21, 22. and not the obj.

Comment: Call getId() on object then.

Comment: Did you resolve this, I have exactly the same problem. The option value is right so something in the handlerequest() is turning it back into a class

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use an anonymous function inside `choice_label`, in order to get the `id`s. And I also think you should rename the field name, and instead of `company_id` simply put `company`.

```
$builder->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
    //...
    'choice_label' => function($company){
        return $company->getId();
    },
//...
```

Moreover, you may need to use the `query_builder` option inside this code, but this thing you'll gonna tell us later, after trying the code I wrote.

LE

For `query_builder`.

```
use use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
//...
$builder->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
//...
`query_builder` => function(EntityRepository $er){
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
},
'choice_label' => function($company){
    return $company->getId();
},
//...
```

Comment: sorry but its not working. the data from drop down is still an object yet the value from options was changed.

Comment: Then you need the `query_builder`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I update my question above, I applied your code and the results are in above.

Comment: I told you to rename that `->add('company_id')` into `->add('company')`.

Comment: Neither the property "company" nor one of the methods "getCompany()", "company()", "isCompany()", "hasCompany()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "MyBundle\Entity\Sub_agent".

Comment: You seem to have a lot of probs before the one for which you've created the OP. You're having a `ManyToOne` relationship, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132564/discussion-between-dan-costinel-and-jlacsonph).

Comment: I just wanted to get the unique value of company and use that value to insert in my database using the sub agent form

Comment: let's continue the discussion in the chat. I'm waitin for you there.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use `choice_value` and then specify the ORM Column name you used in the Entity. I presume below that is `company_id` but you might need to change it. You can also specify the `choice_label` in the same way. It makes coding easier.

```
$builder->add('company_id', EntityType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Company',
    'class' => 'SwipeBundle:Company',
    'choice_value' => 'company_id',
    'choice_label' => 'company_id',
    'placeholder' => 'Choose a Company',
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotBlank(array("message" => 'Company name is required.')),
    ),            
));
```

Let me know if that works. I think it should.

Comment: Still returning the obj not the value only

Comment: Can you check my post again? I edited it again and removed some unnecessary items.

Comment: it still showing the obj not the option value in controller