# Symfony: Why is persist trying to insert an object retrieved by object manager?

Tags: php, doctrine, duplicates, symfony, transformer-model

Apologies if this has been asked before. I'm still trying to grasp Symfony terms to my searching isn't that good yet!

I have (for the purpose of this question) two entities: Article and Author.

I'm embedding the Author form into the add Article form. I'd like to check if the email already exists, and, if it does, just update that record (the corresponding name) instead of adding a duplicate. I'm using a transformer to do this.

I am able to find an existing Author in my transformer. However, when I persist the Article in the controller, I get the error:

> "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO author...
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" ... etc...

I'm really confused because my understanding is that persist should update the record that I just retrieved from the database!

**Article Controller:**

```
    public function newAction(Request $request){
    $article = new Article();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArticleType', $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        //Set the timestamps on article/author.
        $date = new \DateTime("now");
        $article->setCreatedDate($date);
        $article->getAuthor()->setCreatedDate($date);

        //Persist to database.
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush($article);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('article/new.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));}
```

**Article Type:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')->add('description')->add('thumbnail');

        //We'll handle dates. Don't want users to access that.
        //$builder->add('createdDate');

        $builder->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_article';
    }


}
```

**Article Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $author;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $reviews;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumbnail
     *
     * @param string $thumbnail
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail)
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumbnail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDate
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
    {
        $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set authorId
     *
     * @param integer $authorId
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthorId($authorId)
    {
        $this->authorId = $authorId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get authorId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAuthorId()
    {
        return $this->authorId;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $author
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Author
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Add review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function addReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     */
    public function removeReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews->removeElement($review);
    }

    /**
     * Get reviews
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

**Author Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="author")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AuthorRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Note: author already existed. Using that record")
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $reviews;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="article", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDate
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
    {
        $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * Add review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function addReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     */
    public function removeReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews->removeElement($review);
    }

    /**
     * Get reviews
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

    /**
     * Add article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\article $article
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    public function addarticle(\AppBundle\Entity\article $article)
    {
        $this->articles[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\article $article
     */
    public function removearticle(\AppBundle\Entity\article $article)
    {
        $this->articles->removeElement($article);
    }

    /**
     * Get articles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getarticles()
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }

    /**
     *Return boolean depending on if the author has already reviewed the article
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $author
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasarticle(\AppBundle\Entity\article $article)
    {
        return $this->getarticles()->contains($article);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help you can give. Also, is this the best way to handle duplicate emails? I'd like to update the firstname/lastname as well instead of just letting leaving the existing name in the database. Should I update the name in the controller before persisting or should that somehow be done in the transformer?

Thanks!

Comment: I have an update on this. There are several things wrong with what I was trying to do. For one, this transformer was on "Author" instead of "Article." So I dont' think it was even being trigged, right? Also, it's taking email and returning an Author. So I need to move the transformer to Article and apply it to the Author entity. Now the problem is that

        $builder->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE));

        //$builder->get('author')->addModelTransformer($transformer);

Doesn't work. Any ideas? Maybe suited for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine tries to insert new row into the db because you are calling `persist($article)`. If you meant to update the row then just call `flush()`:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

#### LE

For this example, I'm using two lighter entities:

1) `AppBundle/Entity/Article.php` entity contains only `id`, `name`, and `author`, with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="articles")
 */
private $author;

public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
{
    $this->author = $author;
    return $this;
}

//getAuthor()...
//getters for id and name + setter for name
```

2) `AppBundle/Entity/Author.php` entity contains only `id`, `email`, and `articles`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $articles;

//getters for id and email + setter for email

public function __construct()
{
    $this->articles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->articles[] = $article;
    return $this;
}

public function removeArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->articles->removeElement($article);
}

public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->articles;
}
```

3) `AppBundle/Form/ArticleType.php`:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('author', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Author',
        'placeholder' => ' ',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('a');
        },
        'choice_label' => function($author) {
            return $author->getEmail();
        },
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false
    ])
;
```

4) `AppBundle/Controller/ArticleController.php`

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="article_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArticleType', $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_edit', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('article/edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

5) `app/Resources/views/article/edit.html.twig`

```
{{ form(form, { attr:{ 'id':'form' }) }}
<button type="submit" form="form">Update</button>
```

Basically, this code is generated by the `bin/console doctrine:generate:crud AppBundle:Article`

Comment: Thanks for the input. If I replace the persist line with the one you provided then I get "Entity has to be managed or scheduled for removal for single computation (article name)." Is this because, while that would work to update the author, it won't write the article to thedatabase? How could I fix that?

Also, would I still need the "$em->flush($article);" afterwards?

Comment: Never got an error like that, but I guess its because I think you didn't set up correctly the ManyToOne relationship. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41521242/4548751).

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that the Author.php and Article.php files are correct... I'm having a hard time relating the discussion in that link to my issue. Are you saying that, perhaps, at some point I should be passing a value rather than an Author object? 
EDIT: I've updated my question to include my Author.php file

Comment: One other point of interest... I was reading on this second error and read: "Merge attaches the Entity to the Entity Manager as Managed" SO, I added $em->merge($fundraiser);above the ...->getManager()->flush() line and I'm back to the original error.

Comment: @user2305673 Let's start again, as I re-read again your problem, and I'm not 100% sure what you want. And because in some days from now, I'll need similar functionality, I'm really interested in solving this. So, you basically want to update, for eg, the name of the Author only if the email already exists in the db?

Comment: Sounds good @dancostinel. That's correct. I went another route and got another solution (posted about separately here) but I'd REALLY, REALLY like to figure out how to do this via transformer. Seems like it'd be cleaner.

Comment: @user2305673 Unless this is a project requirement, using transformers seems overkill to me. Why would you want to use that, when the solution is much more easier and straightforward? I'll update my answer to post my try.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really trying to learn as much about Symfony as possible. I had read another article where they were saying transformers were definitely the way to go for this kind of thing and plus I wasn't sure if putting this particular logic in the controller was bad form. Also, now, I'm just really curious as to why I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add hidden type of ID field in your form
2. Use `merge`, not `persist` in your controller action

Form type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Add hidden type of ID field
    $builder->add('id', HiddenType::class);

    $builder->add('name')->add('description')->add('thumbnail');

    //We'll handle dates. Don't want users to access that.
    //$builder->add('createdDate');

    $builder->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE));
}
```

Controller action:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArticleType', $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $date = new \DateTime("now");
        $article->setCreatedDate($date);
        $article->getAuthor()->setCreatedDate($date);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Use merge, not persist
        $em->merge($article);

        $em->flush($article);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('article/new.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I added an update in a comment to the question. I might not be following but adding an author ID in the article form isn't an option because I'd like, for this toy project anyways, for people to enter author information at the time of submitting an article. If the email of the author exists, then just update the first/last name on new article submission.